# Table not displaying properly

Tags: tables

i have the same code for both tables, but the second table is not displaying properly. these both tables are on the same page[image]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \label{tab:fir}
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=15cm, height=5.0cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Techniques/tools}} & \multicolumn{6}{p{13.5cm}|}{\centering\textbf{Traditional project scope definition}}\\  \cline{2-7}
            &Controlling Scope & Scope Estimation & Measure Completeness & Identifying Features&Scope Quantification & Ref \\
            \hline
            Function Points & $1$ & $1$ & $0$&$1$ & $1$ & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\
            \hline 
            Expert Judgment & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$& $0$ & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Performance Analysis & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\
            \hline 
            Work-Breakdown Structure (WBS) & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$  &$1$ & \cite{hans2013work}\\
            \hline
            Feature Transition charts & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\

            \hline 
            Stakeholder Analysis & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Benefits Analysis& $0$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\
            \hline 
            Scope Change Control System&$1$ & $0$ & $0$&$0$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Functional Size Measurement (FSM) & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ &$1$ & $1$ & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\


            \hline 
            Feature Survival Charts& $1$ & $0$&  $0$& $0$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
            SEER-SEM& $0$ & $1$&  $0$& $0$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
        Feature Growth Charts& $1$ & $0$&  $0$& $0$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
            SPSRI& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}




\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \label{tab:fir}
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=15cm, height=5.0cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Techniques/tools}} & \multicolumn{6}{p{13.5cm}|}{\centering\textbf{Agile project scope definition}}\\  \cline{2-7}
            &Controlling Scope & Scope Estimation & Measure Completeness &Identifying Features&Scope Quantification & Ref \\
            \hline
            Feature-Breakdown Structure (WBS)  & $1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\
            \hline 
            Feature Transition charts & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$& $0$ & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Story Mapping & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\
            \hline 
            Agile EVM & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$  &$0$ & \cite{hans2013work}\\
            \hline
            Burn Up charts & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\

            \hline 
            Feature Survival Charts & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Burn Down Chart& $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\
            \hline 
            Requirement Matrix&$1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            TinyPM, ScrumDesk, Agile for Trac, Version one & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\


            \hline 
            Cumulative Flow& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 

            Stacked Area Chart& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Iteration Status Chart& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Agilefant& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Iceberg List& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Kanban Board& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Tree Map& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Parking Lot Diagram& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Task Board& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Planning Poker& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Wideband Delphi& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Constructive Cost Model& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            AgileMOW& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 



        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: try to avoid ever scaling tables and absolutely always avoid specifying both height and width when scaling, otherwise you are specifying that the text is to be distorted and you get what you ask for! `\begin{adjustbox}{width=15cm, height=5.0cm}`

Comment: you said the second table isn't correct but the font is visibly distorted in both, remove the height= setting on both tables (although removing adjustbox altogether would be better. Note that no one can run your example as you only posted a fragment. Without knowing your page size it is hard to suggest how to format the table without scaling.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I  marked up your first table so that it fits in A4 without `adjustbox` but note that the actual table data is really quite small, the space is all taken up with over-long headings. I did not change them but with yoru subject knowledge you can perhaps come up with more abbreviated headings to make the table more readable. It would also loo a lot better without the horizontal and vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

    \caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}
    \label{tab:fir}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \centering

        \begin{tabular}{@{}|>{\raggedright}p{1.7cm}|r|r|r|r|r|r|@{}}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\hd{Techniques\\/\\tools}}} & 
\multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Traditional project scope definition}}\\
  \cline{2-7}
            &
\hd{Controlling\\Scope}&
\hd{Scope\\Estimation}&
\hd{Measure\\Completeness}&
\hd{Identifying\\Features}&
\hd{Scope\\Quantification}&
Ref\\
            \hline
            Function Points & $1$ & $1$ & $0$&$1$ & $1$ & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\
            \hline 
            Expert Judgment & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$& $0$ & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Performance Analysis & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\
            \hline 
            Work-Breakdown Structure (WBS) & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$  &$1$ & \cite{hans2013work}\\
            \hline
            Feature Transition charts & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\

            \hline 
            Stakeholder Analysis & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Benefits Analysis& $0$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\
            \hline 
            Scope Change Control System&$1$ & $0$ & $0$&$0$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Functional Size Measurement (FSM) & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ &$1$ & $1$ & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\


            \hline 
            Feature Survival Charts& $1$ & $0$&  $0$& $0$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
            SEER-SEM& $0$ & $1$&  $0$& $0$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
        Feature Growth Charts& $1$ & $0$&  $0$& $0$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
            SPSRI& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\

            \hline 
        \end{tabular}

\end{table}



\end{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Tool/technique for scope definition}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \label{tab:fir}
    \centering

        \begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Techniques/tools}} & \multicolumn{6}{p{13.5cm}|}{\centering\textbf{Agile project scope definition}}\\  \cline{2-7}
            &Controlling Scope & Scope Estimation & Measure Completeness &Identifying Features&Scope Quantification & Ref \\
            \hline
            Feature-Breakdown Structure (WBS)  & $1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sillitti2011agile} \\
            \hline 
            Feature Transition charts & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$& $0$ & \cite{levin2009fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Story Mapping & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{corral2011evolution}\\
            \hline 
            Agile EVM & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$  &$0$ & \cite{hans2013work}\\
            \hline
            Burn Up charts & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{wnuk2009feature}  \\

            \hline 
            Feature Survival Charts & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            Burn Down Chart& $1$ & $0$ & $0$ &$0$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals}  \\
            \hline 
            Requirement Matrix&$1$ & $0$ & $1$&$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sanghera2008fundamentals} \\
            \hline 
            TinyPM, ScrumDesk, Agile for Trac, Version one & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ &$1$ & $0$ & \cite{sliger2008software}  \\


            \hline 
            Cumulative Flow& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 

            Stacked Area Chart& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Iteration Status Chart& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Agilefant& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Iceberg List& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Kanban Board& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Tree Map& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Parking Lot Diagram& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Task Board& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Planning Poker& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Wideband Delphi& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            Constructive Cost Model& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 
            AgileMOW& $1$ & $0$&  $1$& $1$& $0$ & \cite{wnuk2008visualization}  \\
            \hline 



        \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note the second table isn't used here as I added an extra `\end{document}`: the same styling can be applied to both tables once the first table styling is complete.